# testing whether two correlation coefficients are different from a non zero value

Tags: hypothesis-testing, correlation, statistical-significance

Hello I have 2 bivariate normal populations with correlation coefficients p1 and p2 respectively. I could easily obtain samples from both. I am interested in testing whether the difference in these correlations is a equal to c. In other words the null hypothesis is H0: p1 - p2 = c  . I know you could test H0: p1 - p2 = 0 using fisher transformation but don't this this is possible for this case.

Comment: Perhaps establish a confidence interval for the difference and see if it includes $c$?

Comment: How would you go about obtaining a confidence interval when you don't know the distribution of the estimator p1_hat - p2_hat?

Answer (score 0):

One approach might be to use confidence intervals. Suppose we have two coefficients $r_1$ and $r_2$ based on independent samples of $n_1$ and $n_2$ observations respectively. Transform each into the appropriate Fisher $z$. The the standard error of the difference $z_1 - z_2$ is

$$
\sqrt{\frac{1}{n_1 - 3} + \frac{1}{n_2 - 3}}
$$

So a confidence interval can be established for any desired confidence coefficient by multiplying the standard error by the corresponding normal deviate and taking that value either side of $z_1 - z_2$. The convert back to the scale of $r$ if desired and check whether $c$ lies within the limits.